# Anydesk issue with remote connectivity

Tags: anydesk

I've got a weird issue popping up wherein any system that I use anydesk with will get to the 'Please wait for remote system to accept' screen and then once they accept my anydesk just crashes. This is consistent whether with windows or linux systems. Also, when I try and connect via a windows system to my ubuntu 20.04 system, it does the exact same thing. I have tried to use the switch sides option as well but no go.
Can anybody try and help me figure out what could be the problem? I've reinstalled anydesk thrice now including purging it completely twice. I also don't have Wayland enabled.